# ubi-partman error code 141 on Xubuntu 14.10

Tags: partitioning, xubuntu

As title says, I am currently trying to install Xubuntu 14.10 (the Plasma 4 version) on an acer laptop.

My current partition config. is this:

```
Device     Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2  *    206848 381646847 381440000 181,9G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

there are roughly 100 GB of unallocated space.

I am loading Xubuntu from the Hard Disk via Unetbootin and I get the following error when attempting to install: "ubi-partman failed with exit code 141. Further information may be found in /var/log/syslog. Do you want to try running this step again before continuing? If you do not, your installation may fail entirely or may be broken."
right before being able to access the partition table.
I am aware there was a bug regarding multiple systems, one of which is Ubuntu but I don't believe this is the case.
Other than that, everything works fine, the image boots up, I'm able to use the live version of the system but I am not able to install it.
Any suggestions?